# Ubuntu 14. 04 Built-in mic not recording/working

Tags: 14.04, sound, microphone

I'm new to Ubuntu, so preemptive apologies if I have inane questions.
A few weeks ago, my internal mic stopped working/registering sound, and I have *no idea* why. *(It actually worked out of the box in skype, which I've read was an issue for some people?)*

I did try it with a set of earphones that have a mic attached, and that works.  However, I dislike using those, since I'll have to press a button ever time I want to speak (as well as finding the earphones just plain uncomfortable).

I've tried a few 'fixes' that I've found online, but the input level doesn't change; I'm don't think it's picking up any noise.
(It'll do a 'mic pop' noise, if my headphones are plugged in, and I do mute/unmute, but that's about it. )

Alsamixer settings: [alsamixer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcBGO.png)

pavucontrol settings: [pavucontrol screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KheAu.png)

I've also added `alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel` and `options snd-hda-intel model=auto` to my alsa-base.conf file, but that doesn't seem to have made any changes.

Computer info:

- My laptop only comes with one jack.
- Laptop: Toshiba Protege R30-A
- OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Sounds very much a like a hardware error having nothing to do with Ubuntu. Especially since you do not have problems with sound recording in general.

You wouldn't happen to run another operating system parallel to Ubuntu so you can try the mic in a different environment?

Comment: Oh, lovely (luckily I'm still under the 1-yr warranty).  I have duel booting with win7; the last time I was on there the mic didn't work either, but I didn't do much searching around.

Comment: OK! In such case (if it is OS-independent) you should probably make use of the warranty and let them replace it for you.

Comment: You wouldn't have played with the microphone settings in Audacity, would you?